# Protect Codeigniter application during development

Tags: codeigniter, .htpasswd

How can I protect my webapp build with Codeigniter with a htpasswd during development?
I tried this but I get 500 error.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authenticate please"
AuthUserFile /usr/html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|files|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your auth looks ok to me I have below that works fine.  Are you sure you've created your .htpasswd file correctly and it lives at the location you specified?

```
<Files *>
AuthName "Please Login"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
require valid-user
</Files>
```

I would say something is wrong with your rewrite cond and rules.  Any reason you are not using the one here -> http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite

Comment: How does your complete htaccess file look?

Comment: @JonathanClark exactly as it shows on the link I provided with the auth stuff at the very top

Comment: @JonathanClark just curious what was the issue since you've accepted my answer?